# Instantiate a new tinyMce on the go

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have just included my first tinyMCE bit of code, works absolutely great. However, In one part of my project, I dynamically create textareas that must also have tinyMCE enabled.. How do i go about adding tinymce to the new textarea i create.

At the moment, this is firing globally:

```
        function LoadTinymce()
        {
            tinymce.init({
                menu: { 
                    file: false, 
                    edit: {title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste | selectall'}, 
                    insert: {title: 'Insert', items: '|'}, 
                    view: {title: 'View', items: 'visualaid'}, 
                    format: {title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'}, 
                    table: {title: 'Table'}, 
                    tools: {title: 'Tools'} 
                },
                selector: ".tinymce"
             });
        }
        LoadTinymce();
```

When i click on the button that creates my new textarea, what might i be calling to apply a new tiny mce rte on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do! Click on fiddle link below. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/ttXvb/

```
(function($) {

    function loadTinymcsConfig(){
        tinymce.init({
            menu: { 
                file: false, 
                edit: {title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste | selectall'}, 
                insert: {title: 'Insert', items: '|'}, 
                view: {title: 'View', items: 'visualaid'}, 
                format: {title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'}, 
                table: {title: 'Table'}, 
                tools: {title: 'Tools'} 
            },
            selector: ".tinymce"
        });
    };
    loadTinymcsConfig();
    var textareaHtmlTmpl = '<textarea class=\'tinymce\'></textarea>';
    $('.addtextarea').on('click', function(){
        $('body').append(textareaHtmlTmpl);
        loadTinymcsConfig();
     });

})($);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy, all you need to do is to call the tinymce mceAddcontrol command in combination with the id of the newly created textarea:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, "your_textarea_id");
```

Comment: I can't get this one to work. I assume it really does need an id to apply it to? I am doing: tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, ".tinymce"); and i've tried tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, textareaobject); to no avail